# regular expression get string between :: without any whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have trouble with regex. I'm coding smile system.And get smile codes from string with regex, for example `:laugh:` or `:haha:`.
And I want to get string between `::` without anything but alpha characters.

```
<?php
$a="hello my dear :smile: ho r u?";
$a=preg_replace("/:([a-zA-Z]):/","<b>$1</b>",$a);
//or
$a=preg_replace("/:(\w):/","<b>$1</b>",$a);
echo $a;
?>
```

None of these regexs work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try using your `[a-zA-Z]` all by itself, and see what happens

Comment: $a = preg_replace("/:([a-zA-Z]+):/","<b>$1</b>",$a);
I used that,and it works :)

Comment: But, if you don't know how it works, it's of no use to you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allow one or more matchings with `+` quantificator:
This should work:

```
$a = preg_replace("/:([a-zA-Z]+):/","<b>$1</b>",$a);
```

Comment: Oh thank you.I'm not well at regex that's why I get some problems.It definetly works :)